# OLE Procedures, query executed succesfully; No File Extracted

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to extract a blob file from SQL Server. I was able to get it to execute successfully but when I look in my Desktop\consol\output directory, the file isn't there (refreshed, still nothing). Here is the code:

```
SELECT * FROM FileWarehouse

sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  
sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;  
GO  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  


DECLARE @SQLIMG VARCHAR(MAX),
        @File VARBINARY(MAX), 
        @OpPath VARCHAR(MAX),
        @ObjectToken INT 


SELECT     @File = StoredFile FROM [dbo].[FileWarehouse] WHERE Id= 157994
SET        @OpPath = 'C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\consol\output\marksheet.doc'
EXEC       sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @ObjectToken OUTPUT 
EXEC       sp_OASetProperty @ObjectToken, 'Type', 1
EXEC       sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Open' 
EXEC       sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Write', NULL, @File 
EXEC       sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'SaveToFile', NULL, @OpPath, 2
EXEC       sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Close'
EXEC       sp_OADestroy @ObjectToken
GO
```

In the SELECT statement, dbo.[FileWarehouse] and StoredFile are both underlined, saying 'Invalid Object Name' and 'Invalid Column Name', respectively. They are definitely valid, so I'm not sure it's saying that. Here is the tutorial I was following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8g7_F3Ice6E .

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Dan. I need to figure out how to run queries in PowerShell.

Comment: I moved my PowerShell comment to an answer with an example.

Answer (score 1):

While Dan's answer is correct (use Powershell or SQL CLR instead), the reason your COM automation isn't working, is that you've failed to capture and inspect the return codes from the extended stored procedures.

Here's an example:

```
--exec sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1
--reconfigure 
--exec sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1
--reconfigure

declare @url varchar(2000) = 'http://www.bing.com'

declare @hr int;
declare @win int;

begin try

  EXEC @hr=sp_OACreate 'WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1',@win OUT 
  IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win 

  EXEC @hr=sp_OAMethod @win, 'Open',NULL,'GET',@url,'false'
  IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win 

  EXEC @hr=sp_OAMethod @win,'Send'
  IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win 

  declare @status int
  EXEC @hr=sp_OAGetProperty @win,'Status', @status out
  IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win

  if @status <> 200
  begin;
    declare @msg varchar(2000) = concat('web request failed ', @status);
    throw 60000, @msg, 1;
  end;

  declare @response table(text nvarchar(max));

  insert into @response(text)
  EXEC @hr=sp_OAGetProperty @win,'ResponseText';
  IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win;

  select * from @response;

  EXEC @hr=sp_OADestroy @win 
  IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win;

end try
begin catch

  EXEC @hr=sp_OADestroy @win 
  IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @win;
  throw;

end catch
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer David. I'm not exactly grasping what you're saying though. The code worked for the creator of the tutorial that I followed.

Comment: @Nick He's saying that the sp_OA* stored procedures return errors that will very likely tell you where the problem is. You're assuming that the code you found will magically work on any system. That's not the case.  You need to capture the return codes and determine which one is failing and why. It could be file system permissions or network problems. There's no way to determine the problem from just the code.

Answer (score 0):

The IntelliSense error is erroneous if the script runs.

I suggest you generally avoid the ole automation procs for new development. If you don't really need to use T-SQL to create the file, consider a simple PowerShell script. This is more robust and flexible for ad-hoc needs. Below is an example that uses the standard ADO.NET objects.

```
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection("Data Source=YourServer;Initial Catalog=YourDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI")
$command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT StoredFile FROM [dbo].[FileWarehouse] WHERE Id= 157994;", $connection)
$connection.Open()
$blob = $connection.ExecuteScalar()
$connection.Close()
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("C:\Users\Nick\Desktop\consol\output\marksheet.doc", $blob)
```